# Trying to add a title property to a label to use in a webpartcontrol

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to add a title to web label control.  Here is the code where I am trying to use a title on a label:

```
                    <asp:WebPartZone ID="WebPartZone1" runat="server"
                 HeaderText="Welcome to my web page!"
                LayoutOrientation="horizontal" Width="160px">
                    <ZoneTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"
                        **Title**="Welcome to my web page!">
                        Welcome to the page!
                        </asp:Label>
                    </ZoneTemplate>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Tom Magaro

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to do with the Title specifically?  If you want a custom property on a label control you will need to create a custom control that inherits from the Label control.  If you just want to set the text then use the Text property.  If you want a tooltip then set the ToolTip property.

Comment: Hey bechbd, I have created a class that derives from System.Web.UI.Controls.Label and added a title property.  Now I am trying to add it to the webpartcontrol's control collection, but I get an error saying webpartcontrols do not accept child controls.  Here is the code for the class and the aspx page load event:

Comment: So what exactly are you trying to do with the Title?  Is this supposed to be a label at the top of the webpartzone that you can change the text of?